# A regular expression to match a set of strings

Tags: java, regex

I need to match a set of strings in Java. This string can contain self ending HTML, one or more white spaces and one or more `&nbsp;`s.

For example:

```
String html = "<p>Stack Overflow is a great site. I really like Stack<br/>Overflow. Stack&nbsp;&nbsp;Overflow has helped me a lot to learn different things. I frequently visit Stack<br></br>Overflow. Stack<div id=\"XX\" />Overflow is really nice.<p><br/><p>Stack and overflow are two different thing.</p>".
```

Now I need a regular expression which would match the following strings in the above string.

```
 1. Stack Overflow 
 2. Stack<br/>Overflow
 3. Stack&nbsp;&nbsp;Overflow
 4. Stack<br></br>Overflow
 5. Stack<div id=\"XX\" />Overflow
```

But it shouldn't match

- Stack and overflow

Comment: This sounds dangerously close to [using a regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Are you sure you don't need some sort of HTML parser?

Comment: See I could have used any standard html parser like jSoup but as per requirement I have to use regex only.

Comment: Is this homework? Why must you use regex only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stack(<.*?>|&nbsp;|\s)*overflow
```

Comment: It's matching the following items -
1. "stack<br/>overflow"
2. "stack<br></br>overflow"
3. "stack<div id=\"XX\" />overflow".

But it's unable to match

1. stack overflow.
2. stack'&nbsp;&nbsp;'overflow.

Comment: This has really helped me. Thanks a ton dear. Can you please tell me from where I can learn regex in head first way.

Comment: self taught :) stackoverflow.com, gskinner.com/RegExr

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to match "stack" followed by "overflow" with allowing some optional text between them. If this is what you want, how about this:

`(?i)stack.*?overflow`

This will not behave very well if your input string contains "stack" but no corresponding "overflow".

You can learn more about java's regular expression syntax @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: yeah you are correct but the things is that I will only allow 
1. valid htmL
2. one or more spaces.
3. one or more "&nbsp;"

But won't allow other things.

Comment: I have already confessed that I am a beginner in regex. I don't have any problem with Java. I need only the regex or the hint that how to build this complex regex.

Comment: @user1061692: Gowtham gave you the hint that you need, which is to learn more Java's regular expression syntax by reading through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.